# ASP.NET MVC3 JQuery dialog with partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I can't get my head around how to do this correctly:

I'm working on a simple user membership application that is used to assign application roles to users. All I'm trying to do is popup an JQueryUI dialog that has a DropdownBox with all of the available applications and a dynamic checkbox list that will list the available roles for the selected application.

It needs to look like this (simple!):

[image]

I have managed to get the dialog box to display correctly thanks to Richard Covo's tutorial [here](http://ricardocovo.com/2012/04/06/asp-mvc3-editing-records-with-jqueryui-dialogs-and-ajaxforms-razor-version/).

The code for the dropdownlist looks like this:

```
<label for='ApplicationsDropdownList'>Application:</label>

 @Html.DropDownListFor(
        x => x.SelectedApplicationId,
        new SelectList(Model.Applications, "Value", "Text"),
        "-- Select Application --",
             new
             {
                 id = "ApplicationsDropdownList",
                 data_url = Url.Action("ViewUserRolesForApplication", "UserRole")
             }
    ) 

</div>
<br />   <div id="RolesForApplication"></div>
```

And this is how I dynamically load the checkbox list of roles available for the selected application:

```
$('#ApplicationsDropdownList').change(function () {
            var url = $(this).data('url');
            var applicationId = $(this).val();
            $('#RolesForApplication').load(url, { applicationId: applicationId, selectedUserId: SelectedUserId })
        });
    });
```

The checkbox list is generated using the MVC checkboxlist extension:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveUsersRoles", "Index", FormMethod.Post))
{    


    @Html.CheckBoxList("Roles",                         // NAME of checkbox list (html 'name' property of each       
                   x => x.Roles,                        // data source (list of 'Cities' in our case)
                   x => x.RoleId,                       // field from data source to be used for checkbox VALUE
                   x => x.Code + " " + x.Description,   // field from data source to be used for checkbox TEXT
                   x => x.RolesForUser,
                   new HtmlListInfo(HtmlTag.table, 1))   
}
```

The popup is displaying correctly and the roles are populating correctly but my confusion comes arises when saving. I'm assuming there should only be one viewmodel for this situation (I currently have 2), something like this:

```
public class ApplicationsForUserViewModel
{
    public Guid SelectedUserId  {get;set;}
    public int SelectedApplicationId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Applications { get; set; }

    public Application Application { get; set; }
    public IList<Role> Roles { get; set; } //all available roles
    public IList<Role> RolesForUser { get; set; } //roles that the user has selected

}
```

When pressing the save button on the dialog I enter the Edit method on the Index controller but the checkbox list is generated on a different form from a different controller, so how can I successfully model bind? Is there an easy way to do this?

Let me know if you would like to see more of the code so that you can point out further where I'm going wrong!

**EDIT:** The save button is currently hooked up to the edit action on the index controller.

Edit view:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", "Index", new AjaxOptions
        {
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            OnSuccess = "updateSuccess"
        }, new { @id = "EditUserRolesForm" }))
```

and the jQuery UI dialog:

```
 $('#AddRolesDialog').dialog({                     
                buttons: {
                    "Save": function () {                      
                      $("#update-message").html('');
                      $("#EditUserRolesForm").submit();
                    }
                }
            });
```

So the dropdown is currently on the EditUserRoles form, while the checkbox list is on a seperate form - is this the right way to do it and should I rather be submitting the checkbox list form?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your POST controller action could directly take the list of selected role ids:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveUsersRoles(int[] roles)
{
    // the roles parameter will contain the list of ids of roles 
    // that were selected in the check boxes so that you could take 
    // the respective actions here
    ...
}
```

Now I suppose that you might also need the user id. So define a view model:

```
public class SaveUsersRolesViewModel
{
    public Guid SelectedUserId { get; set; }
    public int[] Roles { get; set; }
}
```

And then have your controller action take this view model:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveUsersRoles(SaveUsersRolesViewModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

and of course don't forget to include the user id as part of the form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveUsersRoles", "Index", FormMethod.Post))
{    
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.SelectedUserId)
    @Html.CheckBoxList(
        "Roles",
        x => x.Roles,
        x => x.RoleId,
        x => x.Code + " " + x.Description,
        x => x.RolesForUser,                       
        new HtmlListInfo(HtmlTag.table, 1)
    )
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response! I think my main problem is that I have 2 forms on the popup - one for the dropdownlist and one for the checkbox list. I'll update my question with this info about how it is hooked up to the save button on the dialog. I'll fiddle with code a bit to see if I can get the save button hooked up the the SaveUsersRoles action.

Comment: I hope that those 2 forms are not nested. Because if they are you will have to un-nest them. Nesting HTML forms is not allowed by the specification and results in an undefined behavior by the user agents.

Comment: I use $('#RolesForApplication').load(url, { applicationId: applicationId, selectedUserId: SelectedUserId }) to load the checkbox list partial view into the div...I guess this means it is nested?

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with the nested `<form>` elements in your markup which you are not allowed to do. You should not nest forms otherwise it won't work. Look at your markup and see if there are nested form elements. But since you are using AJAX you will probably be better of using a DOM explorer tool such as FireBug. But anyway if you have nested forms it means that you have broken markup.

Comment: They are nested! I'll ask a question about how to properly dynamically load a checkboxlist from a dropdown.